# Javascript + jQuery, click handler returning false to stop browser from following link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to stop the browser from following certain links, rather I want to unhide some Divs when they are clicked.

I'm having trouble just getting the links to not be followed though.

Here's what I have:

```
var titles = $('a.highlight');
jquery.each(titles, function(){
    this.click(function(){
        return false;
    });
});
```

It seems like the click handler is not being assigned. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
this.click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
```

Actually, it looks like you might need to use the jQuery constructor on `this`:

```
$(this).click(function(){ return false; }
```

You could also try using parameters on the `each` function instead of using `this`:

```
jQuery.each( titles, function(index, elem) { $(elem).click( function() { return false; } ) } );
```

Personally, I would just do `titles.each( ...` though.  In that instance you can use `this` to bind the click handler.  I am not sure off the top of my head what `this` binds to with `jQuery.each`

Or just calling `click` on `titles`:

```
titles.click( function() { return false; } )
```

That will bind click to every element in `titles`.  You don't need to loop through them.

Comment: Yep, that's it.  Just using `this` returns a dom object.  Using $(this) returns a jquery object which is necessary for attaching a handler using the .click function.

Comment: By the way, I just looked it up and `this` in the `jQuery.each` function does refer to the object currently being iterated on.

Comment: @Tinister - really? Do you have a link? (I do believe you, I just wanna see :))

Comment: Uh, http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each -- I initially thought `this` might've been something different for some weird reason.

Comment: @Tinister - I don't think that's correct. For example, try `$.each($('li'), function() { this.click(); });` and compare it to `$.each($('li'), function() { $(this).click(); });` One works and one doesn't: `.click` is not a function of `this`, but it is a function of `$(this)`.

Comment: Derp. That's not what I meant. I did not know what `this` for `jQuery.each` was defined as and didn't look it up in my rush to get an answer out. In contrast, I did know that `this` in `$().each` is defined as the dom element that's in the resultant jQuery collection. I knew that for `jQuery.each` (with iterates over anything, not just jQuery collections) you could get the object being iterated on as a parameter, but was unsure what `this` was. Make sense?

Comment: @Tinister - I'm with you. `jQuery.each()` != `$().each`

Answer (score 0):

You can compress that jquery a bit:

```
$('a.highlight').click(function() { return false; });
```

You should also make sure that:

- There are no other click handlers registered for those elements later on.
- The code you have is attaching after the elements have loaded.  If they're not completely loaded, they won't be found in the $('a.highlight') selector.  The easiest way to do this is to put your code in a `$(document).ready(function() { *** code here *** });` block.

**Edit:** As per other responses - the problem was that `this` represents a DOM object, while `$(this)` is a jquery object.  To use the .click function to attach a handler, you need a jquery object.

In short, using `this` inside the each loop won't work with what you're trying to do.  You'll need to get a jquery representation by using `$(this)` instead.